# Variable sized list on Modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

A requirement for my MVC application is to store a banking transaction.

A transaction object, contains transaction lines.

A transaction object can have one or more transaction lines. The values in the transaction lines, sum up, and becomes the total amount of the transaction.

When the user creates a new transaction, one single transaction line is displayed, with an Add button. If they click add, a new transaction line appears, with another Add button. So they can add as many lines as they want.

The Model I send to the View has a List Lines property, and has one row added by default.

I was going to just add 10 lines (There wouldn't be more than 10 .. 99% of the time, there's only one), and then just have hidden lines on the view. But this seems dirty. Is there a way to handle this - client side, adding items to my List<> when ever the Add button is clicked?

Current dodgy code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cmbCategory0" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Category:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Transaction.TransactionLines[0].CategoryId,
                                  new SelectList(Model.TransactionReferences.Categories, "Value", "Text", Model.Transaction.TransactionLines[0].CategoryId), "Select one",
                                  new { @onchange = "populateSubCategory(0)", @class = "cmbCategory0 form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Transaction.TransactionLines[0].SubCategoryId,
                                  new SelectList(Model.TransactionReferences.SubCategories, "Value", "Text", Model.Transaction.TransactionLines[0].SubCategoryId), "Select one",
                                  new { @class = "cmbSubCategory0 form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Transaction.TransactionLines[0].CostCentreId,
                                  new SelectList(Model.TransactionReferences.CostCentres, "Value", "Text", Model.Transaction.TransactionLines[0].CostCentreId), "None",
                                  new { @class = "cmbCostCentre0 form-control" })
    </div>
    <label for="txtAmount0" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Amount:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Transaction.TransactionLines[0].Amount, new { @class = "txtAmount form-control input-money", @placeholder = "Amount", @type = "number", @min = 0, @step = "any" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <a class="btn btn-info btnadd0" onclick="showSplit(0)">Add</a>
    </div>

</div>


<div class="form-group row1 hide">
    <label for="cmbCategory1" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Category:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Transaction.TransactionLines[1].CategoryId,
        new SelectList(Model.TransactionReferences.Categories, "Value", "Text", Model.Transaction.TransactionLines[1].CategoryId), "Select one",
                                  new { @onchange = "populateSubCategory(1)", @class = "cmbCategory1 form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Transaction.TransactionLines[1].SubCategoryId,
        new SelectList(Model.TransactionReferences.SubCategories, "Value", "Text", Model.Transaction.TransactionLines[1].SubCategoryId), "Select one",
                                  new { @class = "cmbSubCategory1 form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Transaction.TransactionLines[1].CostCentreId,
        new SelectList(Model.TransactionReferences.CostCentres, "Value", "Text", Model.Transaction.TransactionLines[1].CostCentreId), "None",
                                  new { @class = "cmbCostCentre1 form-control" })
    </div>
    <label for="txtAmount" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Amount:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Transaction.TransactionLines[1].Amount, new { @class = "txtAmount form-control input-money", @placeholder = "Amount", @type = "number", @min = 0, @step = "any" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <a class="btn btn-info btnadd1" onclick="showSplit(1)">Add</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

You create a PartialView for the Lines and in your controller you have a method that returns this as a PartialView result. In your view, you use an @Ajax.Action() helper to generate the link while specifying the name of the action in your controller which returns the partial view.

Without snippets of your actual code and views, it's hard to be more specific but that's the broad stroke.

Comment: Thanks Erik! This sounds promising. I'm adding the 'dodgy' way I am doing it now (View code).